# Opam install deriving, syntax error

Tags: ocaml, deriving, opam

So basically I am trying to use Opam to install deriving lib on my Mac.

```
opam install deriving
```

I use `ocamlfind query` and it seems the installation is successful.

```
#ocamlfind query deriving                                                                                                 
/Users/shuai/.opam/system/lib/deriving
```

After install, I try to use ocamlbuild to compile a simple code like this:

```
type stackop = PUSH | POP deriving (Show, Enum)

let s = PUSH in
  let s' = Show.show<stackop> s in 
    print_string s'
```

Here is the _tags file:

```
<*> : package(unix), package(deriving)
```

and here is the command:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind exp.native
```

However, I always get this error:

```
+ ocamlfind ocamldep -package unix -package deriving -modules exp.ml > exp.ml.depends
File "exp.ml", line 1, characters 27-28:
Error: Syntax error
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

This is quite weird, I am sure the syntax is correct..

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot to provide `deriving.syntax` package.

Use the following `_tags` file:

```
true: syntax(camlp4o)
true: package(deriving,deriving.syntax)
true: thread,debug,annot
true: bin_annot
```

Comment: Basically why do I need `syntax(calp4o)` ?

Comment: @computereasy it instructs the compiler to run preprocessor. Deriving is a syntax extension.

Comment: Actually I got a confused problem based on this `tags` file, is it probably because of some syntax difference between `camlp4o` and `OCaml` ?